# How to add sorting to display tag

Tags: java, jstl, jsp-tags, displaytag

I am trying to use sorting option in display tag. Saw a couple of examples online and understand that `sortable="true"` will make the column sortable. Adding `sortable="true"` to the column makes the column hyperlink but onclick nothing happens. I mean it is not sorted either way. Can someone let me know.

This is how the code looks.

```
<display-el:table sort="external" defaultsort="1" htmlId="tbl" id="row" name="tblItems" class="default" style="width:100%" export="false" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" pagesize="10" partialList="true" size="resultSize" decorator="abc.web.testIncludeDecorator" requestURI="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/../${requestScope.requestURI}">
    <display-el:column property="test1" title="abc" sortable="true"  class="defaultTest" style="width:2%;" />
    <display-el:column property="crid" title="def" sortable="true" class="defaultTest" style="width:2%;" />          
    <display-el:column property="sample" title="ghi" sortable="true" class="defaultTest" style="width:2%;" />
</display-el:table>
```

Comment: Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are including sort="external", you are telling displayTag that your backend code is performing the sorting(like implementing Comparable interface) and displayTag help is not required.
If you are including partialList="true", you are telling displayTag, that only partial list of items are to displayed and not full.

If you are learning as to how to use displayTag and its intrinsic sorting behavior and tblItems properties are simple data types like String, int etc.,(for user defined types like a class, you need them to implement Comparable interface again) then replace your first line as and try:

```
    <display-el:table defaultsort="1" htmlId="tbl" id="row" name="tblItems" class="default" style="width:100%" export="false" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" pagesize="10" decorator="abc.web.testIncludeDecorator" requestURI="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/../${requestScope.requestURI}">
```